# QML Cannot create Submenu in Menu

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm trying to create a menu

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

...

Menu {
      id: menu
      title: "mainMenu"
      MenuItem {
         text: "menuItem1"
      }
      MenuItem {
         text: "menuItem2"
      }
      Menu {
          title: "contextMenu"
            MenuItem {
               text: "item1"
            }
            MenuItem {
               text: "item2"
            }
      }
}
```

But when I'm trying `menu.open()` there is no `contextMenu`
Please find a screenshot below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/462NN.png]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: My qt version is 5.9.2

Comment: Maybe some specific WM? Wayland-based, framebuffer or something like this?

Answer (score 3):

[Qt Quick Controls 2.3 (Qt 5.10)](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.10) adds support for [nested menus](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html#details) and [cascading sub-menus](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html#cascade-prop).

Comment: PS. You can already try out Qt 5.10 beta1, which is conveniently available in the online installer. Be aware, though, that due to some ongoing touch and mouse input handling related work in Qt Quick core, the first beta release is known to have some issues in this area. In Qt Quick Controls 2, popups are affected in a way that they don't always close as expected when clicking or tapping outside. These issues have been fixed in the upcoming Qt 5.10 beta2.

Comment: Your links are dead

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to use `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` where those sub-menus are supported.

In `QtQuick.Controls 2.2` - the version you are using - `Menu` inherits from `Popup` and therefore behaves like such - meaning, they are closed by default, and you need to set them `visible` or `open()` them.

The `MenuItem` on the other hand are `AbstractButton`s, that are preconfigured, to close `Popup`s when clicked. If you want to use the `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`-style `Menu` you can define your own child type `SubMenu` which is a button that *does not close the parent `Popup` but opens a second Menu as needed or inserts the right `MenuItem`s when clicked (Accordion-style).*

The right implementation depends on your requirements but should not be too challenging. Feel free to ask, if you need more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Button instead of MenuItem，and adjust the background of Button yourself，Wrap them up

```
Item {
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 500

    MouseArea {
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            rootMenu.open()
        }
    }

    Menu {
        id: rootMenu
        title: "rootMenu"

        Button {
            text: "menuItem1"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("choose A")
                rootMenu.close()
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "menuItem2"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("choose B")
                rootMenu.close()
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: menu_c
            text: "menuItem3"
            onClicked: secondMenu.open()
        }
    }
    Menu {
        id: secondMenu
        x: rootMenu.width
        y: menu_c.y
        MenuItem {
            text: "item1"
            onTriggered: {
                console.log("item1")
                rootMenu.close();
            }
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "item2"
            onTriggered: {
                console.log("item2")
                rootMenu.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```